# Server returning raw php in one file

Tags: php, rendering

I have a file with the following inital code:

```
<?php 

    $body_tags = 'class="careers"';
    $title = "Ensure Security | Security Guards in Wiltshire";
    $keywords = "Ensure, Security, door guard, supervision, covert, guard, guarding, static, event, retail, commercial, security van, dog unit, melksham, Wiltshire, south West, safety, sia, protection, surveillance, rapid response.";
    $description = "Ensure Security are a Wiltshire based company. We strive to provide our clients with the best service. We offer a personal and professional approach. Ensure Security have been established now for 15 years and hold a respectable client portfolio.";

?>
<?php include 'template/head.php'; ?>

        <div class="maincontent">
            <div class="left"> 
                <ul id="navmenu">
```

Which is being sent to the browser as raw text - the php tags and all.
However all other pages in the site are being processed correctly - for example:

```
<?php 

    $body_tags = 'class="services"';
    $title = "Ensure Security | Security Guards in Wiltshire";
    $keywords = "Ensure, Security, door guard, supervision, covert, guard, guarding, static, event, retail, commercial, security van, dog unit, melksham, Wiltshire, south West, safety, sia, protection, surveillance, rapid response.";
    $description = "Ensure Security are a Wiltshire based company. We strive to provide our clients with the best service. We offer a personal and professional approach. Ensure Security have been established now for 15 years and hold a respectable client portfolio.";

?>
<?php include 'template/head.php'; ?>

        <div class="maincontent">
            <div class="left"> 
                <ul id="navmenu">
```

renders correctly.

I have been editing both pages, but not the php in either. What's happening?

edit: could the included file be doing this?

Comment: check the permissions on each file, I would guess that one will be different from the other.

Comment: are you sure they both have `.php` ?????

Comment: file extensions are ok and file permissions are all 644

Comment: have you tried putting the same code into a different file(name) or under a different folder? perhaps you have .htaccess kicking there that disallows (or does not activate) PHP in the folder this file resides in?

Comment: Could be a directory-specific server configuration, .htaccess rule, file extension, or possibly even UTF-encoding issue (I've seen a file with saved as UTF-8 with a Byte Order Mark at the beginning confuse a PHP server before. Check your file's text encoding...)

Comment: I put it in a sub-folder under a different name by creating a blank file and copy/pasting and it rendered normally. There is no .htaccess, ini.php or other config to speak of anywhere on site. not a solution yet but close.

Comment: @Zathus Writer replacing the file with the test one and renaming solved the issue. If you put up an answer I will tick it.